# Is there any way to add metadata to MongoDB Aggregation Queries?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-atlas

Having a lots of apps accessing the MongoDB cluster, slow queries are hard to track. especially when it's an aggregation pipeline.

We're using MongoDB Atlas, where we have a profiler which shows the executed queries which ran beyond a threshold, say 5000ms, and also shows the corresponding collection. We can look at the slow queries but it doesn't give any hint which app has called for it. It requires to do a "find" for the relevant piece of query - throughout the applications in the whole solution. Very time consuming!

At the moment I'm using MongoDB C# Driver.

Is there any way to insert/add any "metadata" in MongoDB queries, like "name" or "calling-application", etc., and get it back from the slow queries section, or from the query logs?

Below is a sample db log (credentials redacted, for reference purpose only)

```
[conn280813] command <database>.<collection> command: aggregate 
{ aggregate: "<collection>", pipeline: [ { $match: { <collection>.
<property2>: "XXXXXXXXXXXX", <collection>.<property3>: 
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", <collection>.<property4>: "XXXXXXX", 
<collection>.<property5>: "XX", <collection>.<property6>: { $gte: 1 
}, <collection>.<property7>: { $gte: new Date(1636730882184) } } }, 
{ $group: { _id: "$<collection>.<property>", count: { $sum: 
"$<collection>.<property>" }, <aggregate-field>: { $first: 
"$<collection>.<property>" } } }, { $sort: { count: -1 } }, { 
$lookup: { from: "<collection>", let: { <out-field>: "$<property>" 
}, pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$<property>" ] 
} } }, { $graphLookup: { from: "<collection>", startWith: "$_id", 
connectFromField: "<property>", connectToField: "_id", as: "
<object>", depthField: "level" } }, { $unwind: "$<object>" }, { 
$unwind: "$<object>.<property>" }, { $match: { <object>.<property>: 
<value> } }, { $group: { _id: "$<object>.<property>", <property>: { 
$push: "$<object>.<property>" }, protectionLevel: { $push: 
"$<object>.<property>" } } }, { $project: { _id: 0, <property>: 
"$_id", <property2>: { $in: [ true, "$<property>" ] }, <property>: 
{ $in: [ 1, "$<property>" ] } } } ], as: "<out-property>" } }, { 
$unwind: { path: "$<property>" } }, { $match: { <object>.
<property>: false } }, { $limit: 50 }, { $lookup: { from: "
<collection>", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "<out-
object>" } }, { $unwind: { path: "$<property>" } }, { $project: { 
<property>: "$_id", count: 1, <property2>: 1, <property3>: 
"$<object>.<property>" } }, { $unwind: { path: "$<property>" } }, { 
$match: { <object>.<property>: "<filter-value>", <object>.
<property>: <value>, <object>.<property>: { $gt: 0 } } }, { 
$project: { <collection>.<property>: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $map: { 
input: { $filter: { input: "$<object>.<property>", as: "version", 
cond: { $eq: [ "$<object>.<property>", "$$<object>.<property>" ] } 
} }, as: "v", in: "$$<property>" } }, 0 ] }, <out-field>: 
"$<property>", <out-field>: "$_id", <out-field>: "$<property>", 
_id: 0 } }, { $lookup: { from: "<collection>", localField: "
<collection>.<property>", foreignField: "_id", as: "<collection>" } 
}, { $project: { <out-field>: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$<collection>.
<property>", 0 ] }, <out-field>: 1, <out-field>: 1, <out-field>: 1 
} }, { $limit: 5 } ], allowDiskUse: false, cursor: {}, $db: "<db>", 
lsid: { id: UUID("XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX") }, $clusterTime: { 
clusterTime: Timestamp(1644506882, 1), signature: { hash: 
BinData(0, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX), keyId: XXXXXXXXXXXXX } } } 
planSummary: IXSCAN { <object>.<property>: 1, <object>.<property>: 
1, <object>.<property>: 1 } keysExamined:12476 docsExamined:12475 
hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:99 nreturned:5 
reslen:1138 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 193 } }, Database: 
{ acquireCount: { r: 193 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 192 
} } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead: 10641559, timeReadingMicros: 
59687 } } protocol:op_msg 263ms
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$comment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/comment/) for this target. You can specify this option in various ways, for aggregation it can be set via [AggregateOptions](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_AggregateOptions_Comment.htm)

Comment: thanks @dododo. I will try this.

Comment: this works just perfect. Thank you!

Comment: btw, MongoClientSettings has `ApplicationName` option that you can use for the same target but it's limited only to the whole MongoClient level

Comment: yes, as recommended by @R2D2 in the other answer. It could be tricky when you have queries from different parts of one application and want to track down the source of it from the logs. I would prefer the comments in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the logs the connectionId : conn280813  , if you search by this id you will find the IP from where the connection was made and the user , best practice is to create user per application so by the user to identify which app is connecting ...

The ACCESS message looks as follow:

```
 2022-02-14T09:27:26.423+0100 I ACCESS   [conn2800813] Successfully authenticated as principal <the_user_name> on admin from client <CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS>:<CLIENT_PORT_NO>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, @R2D2. It's a good point to create one user per app. About the IP, most of our apps are hosted on the cloud within same region, so IPs are same for all of them. But I do get your point about one user per app. Thanks.